# viv.time.Year doesn't accept value before 1900

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Bixby IDE says value '1888' for primitive is invalid, but if you put  1999 as the viv.time.year, it will work fine

Comment: Well everything has its limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please report this to Bixby Support (through Bixby Developer Studio) as a bug.